# Redirection. What is "<>", "<&" and ">&-"?

Tags: io-redirection, ksh

`<>` – This operator I saw few months ago on the one site, but I don't remember what does it mean. Maybe I'm wrong and ksh has no `<>`.

`a<&b` – I know that this operator merge input stream `a` with output stream `b`. Am I right? But I don't know where I can use it. Can you get me examples?

`>&-` – I know nothing about it. For example, what does `2>&-` mean?

Comment: What does your man page say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ksh/:

```
   <>word        Open file word for reading and writing as  standard  out-
                 put.

   <&digit       The standard input is  duplicated  from  file  descriptor
                 digit  (see  dup(2)).   Similarly for the standard output
                 using >&digit.

   <&-           The standard input is closed.  Similarly for the standard
                 output using >&-.
```

You will find all those details by typing `man ksh`.

Especially `2>&-` means: close the standard error stream, i.e. the command is no longer able to write to STDERR, which will break the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stdin.html) which requires it to be writable.

---

To understand the concept of file descriptors, *(if on a Linux system)* you may have a look at `/proc/*/fd` *(and/or `/dev/fd/*`)*:

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
insgesamt 0
lrwx------ 1 michas users 1 18. Jan 16:52 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 michas users 1 18. Jan 16:52 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 michas users 1 18. Jan 16:52 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 michas users 1 18. Jan 16:52 3 -> /proc/2903/fd
```

File descriptor 0 (aka STDIN) is used per default for reading, fd 1 (aka STDOUT) is default for writing, and fd 2 (aka STDERR) is default for error messages. (fd 3 is in this case used by `ls` to actually read that directory.)

If you redirect stuff it might look like this:

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd 2>/dev/null </dev/zero 99<>/dev/random |cat
insgesamt 0
lr-x------ 1 michas users 1 18. Jan 16:57 0 -> /dev/zero
l-wx------ 1 michas users 1 18. Jan 16:57 1 -> pipe:[28468]
l-wx------ 1 michas users 1 18. Jan 16:57 2 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 michas users 1 18. Jan 16:57 3 -> /proc/3000/fd
lrwx------ 1 michas users 1 18. Jan 16:57 99 -> /dev/random
```

Now the default descriptors do no longer point to your terminal but to the corresponding redirects. (As you see, you can also create new fds.)

---

One more example for `<>`:

```
echo -e 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3' > foo # create a new file with three lines
( # with that file redirected to fd 5
  read <&5            # read the first line
  echo "xxxxxx">&5    # override the second line
  cat <&5             # output the remaining line
) 5<>foo  # this is the actual redirection
```

You can do such things, but you very seldom have to do so.

Comment: **<>word** - Will program read and after that append input to _word_? **<&digit** -  So, will stderr will regirection to stdin if I write "<&2"?

Comment: @NikolayBildeyko `<` is input rather `>` is output. So stderr is `2>` and to redirrect it use `2>&1`

Comment: @Costas Could give me an example when I can use `<&digit`?

Comment: @NikolayBildeyko See above answer

Comment: @mikeserv In theory you are right. In praxis I never saw such an error. Can you give an example how to provoke such an error?

Comment: Ok, I have seen this kind of construct, but never used it actively myself. A quick check: `echo foo >&-` as a builtin for some reason works without complaining. However `/usr/bin/echo >&-` or `cat file >&-` complains as expected.

Comment: The difference you're seeing is that `echo` *as a `builtin`* exists as a function *(or series of functions)* of the current process and you cut-off stdout only for that function - a survivable condition since the shell process as a whole still owns fds for i/o - but the processes you attempt to fork off for the separate executables have no such luxury and so you witness the results. You might try combining the `exec` builtin with your experiments for more fun and profit. Thanks for the edit by the way - very good answer otherwise. I especially like the `<>` examples